# Run a Command-line Program with an Environment Variable

Tags: command-line, graphics, environment-variables

I am using the mpv media player to play my videos. I have a laptop with hybrid graphics so in order to use the discrete GPU I must use `DRI_PRIME=1 mpv video.mp4` whenever I want to run mpv with the discrete GPU. However, typing `DRI_PRIME=1` everytime is quite annoying, so I was wondering if there is a way to make it so everytime I run mpv `DRI_PRIME=1` is always used.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want only `mpv` to be affected, just alias it:

```
alias mpv='DRI_PRIME=1 mpv'
```

You can add this to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`.

Answer (score 12):

Place that variable into your `~/.bashrc` file like so:

```
export DRI_PRIME=1
```

and run `source ~/.bashrc`. After that this variable will be always in your shell's environment.

**NOTE**: exporting variables allows them to be passed to each and every program you run from shell. For the most part this should not matter, unless you have two programs that expect different value for your variable ( in this case `DRI_PRIME` ). If you intentionally want two programs have different value of `DRI_PRIME`, use muru's answer.

Comment: You beat me to it by 5 seconds :P

Comment: maybe add a note that **every program run from the command line** will use the discrete card which may or may not be what you want

Comment: @cat already added that